# How can I make LLVM display graphs in a different viewer?

Tags: llvm

LLVM can create graphs in [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)'s "dot" format, and automatically invoke a viewer to display them. By default it uses `dotty` to display those graphs. I know that I can change it to use a different viewer, but I was not able to find precise instructions on how to do so.

How can I make it open the graphs with a different viewer?

I'm running on Linux but would be interested in an answer for Windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I'm supposed to change the `CMakeCache.txt` file in my build folder. For instance, to use [XDot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/XDot) instead of dotty, I edited the `LLVM_PATH_XDOT_P` property in that file to point to the full path of my `xdot.py` file.

It now opens the alternative viewer successfully, after rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do this.
I managed to do this with a workaround: made a backup of dotty (just in case) and created a link from dotty to XDot.

```
cp /usr/bin/dotty /usr/bin/dotty_copy
ln -s /usr/bin/dotty /usr/bin/xdot
```

I believe you could also set some variable during configuration step (possibly LLVM_PATH_DOTTY), but I never tried this as I didn't want to recompile LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

You may try hacking the [`DisplayGraph` function](http://llvm.org/doxygen/GraphWriter_8cpp_source.html#l00075) or fidging with the makefiles until you manage to enable one of the `#ifdef`s in `DisplayGraph`.

Comment: I suppose I can, but considering all the ifdefs around, there's surely a more civilized way to do that?

Comment: Probably. I'm more confortable hacking on C++ rather that on makefiles, though.